# antd, Set value in input field based on a selected value in the drop down list

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

What I want is, when I select a particular value from **Templates** drop down, the **Note** textbox should display a value based on the selected value in **Templates** drop down.

```
      <Form.Item label="Templates" name="Templates">
          <Select size="small"
            placeholder="Select..."
            allowClear
            showSearch
            filterOption={(input, option) =>
                option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                }
            onChange ={(e) => 
              {
                const newValue = e;
                const {change} = this.props
              change('Note', _.find( MasterData.NotesTemplates, { TemplateLabel: newValue }).TemplateText)
              this.setState({selectedTemplate: newValue});
            }
            }
          >
            {MasterData && MasterData.NotesTemplates && MasterData.NotesTemplates.map((dd)=><Select.Option value={dd.TemplateLabel}>{dd.TemplateLabel}</Select.Option>)}

            </Select>
      </Form.Item>
<Form.Item label="Note" name="Note" rules={[{required:true,message:'Please Input!'}]}>
              <Input.TextArea autoSize size="small"  />
          </Form.Item>
```

I have used the `change` function in the `onChange` and I am getting this error

> TypeError: change is not a function

What in-built function I can use instead of `change`?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer

```
this.form.setFieldsValue({'Note': _.find( MasterData.NotesTemplates, { TemplateLabel: newValue }).TemplateText})
```